# Make your pythons a little faster

Tags: python, makefile

I'm building python 2.6.6 in a home directory and trying to optimize speed and memory usage for a package I'm using. Reading [this page](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems#make-your-pythons-a-little-faster), one says that `CFLAGS='-g -O2'` is supposed to make it faster.

After some search, I read that it's some kind of flags you pass to compilers but they don't explain why this optimizes python speed (actually, it seems that other values optimize others things, like ruby).

I would like to understand it better in order to get more performance in what I'm doing because currently it takes so much time. Does anybody could explain what do those flags mean and in what sense can it increase python speed? Thank you

Comment: For what it's worth, I need this improvement because `MaxentClassifier` performance in `NLTK` package takes too much time to run in recent versions of python and scipy, thus I try to create this old environment.

Comment: The flags optimize the machine code generated when compiling C. That can potentially make *any* C program run faster, not just Python.

Comment: See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html for explanations what the different optimization levels do. As Martijn said, they apply to every compiled C program, not just Python.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So, can I always use them everytime for all programs in any linux distribution? If this is the case, why C compilers don't put use this flags by default? Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: @rafa: They aren't the default for the compiler, but they are usually turned on for every binary in a typical Linux distribution.

Comment: @rafa Some of the higher optimization levels are not always safe (meaning they can lead to crashes). Also, optimizing for a particular architecture will mean that the resulting binary won't be portable any more. See the [Page about GCC Optimization on the Gentoo Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GCC_optimization) for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The -O2 flag instructs the C compiler to make certain optimization choices, see the [GCC optimization flags documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

The Python interpreter is written in C; optimizing the machine code the compiler produces means the program *could* run faster as the code avoids some common speed bottlenecks. This doesn't apply to just Python.

The downside is that certain aggressive optimizations can introduce errors or *reduce* speed as assumptions made for these optimizations turn out not to be true. What works differs from program to program; without in-depth knowledge of what the optimizations do and a thorough test suite to catch any problems introduced, you should stay away from these flags unless someone who does have that knowledge tells you to use an optimization setting.

You'd be better off focusing on optimising your own Python code instead; there are much bigger gains to be had there. Profile your code, rethink data structures, and if need be, rewrite parts in C as a Python extension. And sometimes it is a fact of the problem space you are tackling that certain tasks take time.

Answer (score 2):

`-O` is a general compiler flag that enables *compiler optimizations*. These optimizations are performed by the compiler to improve performance, particularly compared with not having any optimizations on at all. However, optimizations increase compile times, and some optimizations may make the final code bigger.

In the GCC family of compilers, `-O` can be followed by a letter or number specifying the level of optimization to perform. No optimization is the default (for fastest compiles). `-O` is basic optimizations; `-O2` is more optimizations, and `-O3` is aggressive (and occasionally unsafe) optimizations. The usual level for most projects is `-O2` as it provides good performance improvements without substantially increasing code size or potentially introducing bugs. Additionally, you can use `-Os` instead to minimize code size instead of aiming to increase code speed.

It's worth noting that most released builds of Python will already be built with some level of optimization, so you aren't likely to see huge gains in performance by making your own build. If the program is slow, there may be algorithmic changes you can make to make the program run faster.

`-g` means to generate debugging information, and makes debugging Python easier. It isn't needed unless you're developing for Python, but also won't hurt to leave in (except for making the final binary a bit bigger).